# Clearing cache doesn't work for videos

Tags: php, jquery, caching, video

**About what I'm doing:**

- I'm doing a website where you can search videos.

-I show rows of content with a mini-clip embebed for each row that shows a video.

- I use jQuery.AJAX for retrieve this videos so I don't need to reload the page.
- Everything works fine. I show the videos and I can play them from that rows.
- For administrators of the page I have a button that overwrite that videos. So this put a new video into the location where the old one used to be, replacing it. I do this at server-side with `PHP` doing the following code:

---

```
unlink($destination_path.$video_name.".mov");
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['newVideo']['tmp_name'], $destination_path.$video_name.".mov");
```

Then I use a `header("Location: index.php");` to go to the main page.

**Problems:**

Then when I play the new video in the website I see the old one instead of the new one.

- I clear cache with F5: *Not working*
- I clear cache with Ctrl+F5: *Not working*
- I set this at the top of my page:

*Not working*

- I close the browser and open again (or opening a new one): ***Working***

**Some extra info:**

- The `preload` attr from the video is set to `none`. So I retrieve my videos with no cache. They start loading when I press play on them.
- The files are overwrited pretty well and I also check where I am pointing (same location and same like before).
- If I go to the location of the videos the new is in there, the old is gone.
- Happened to all browsers.

It looks like some cache stuff are in the browser or my server is ignoring me so hard. Is there any other ways to empty cache? Or what is going on here?

Comment: F5 does not clear the cache. CTRL + F5 does not clear the cache, it does a hard reload which reloads all included ressources *on that page*. All other ressources are loaded from the cache (if present). Every modern browser has a clear history/cookie/etc. button. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en

Comment: _“The `preload` attr from the video is set to `none`. So I retrieve my videos with no cache.”_ – preloading has little to do with caching; it just determines whether the browser should start loading the video data automatically, or only when the user starts playback. But of course a browser is allowed to fetch video data from its cache, no matter what `preload` is set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add a time token to the url of your video in your html page.

```
$filepath = $destination_path.$video_name.".mov";
$videoUrl = $wwwpath . $filepath . "?" . filemtime($filepath);
```

Comment: This may solve the problem with the browser caching the file, but if caching is allowed (and also pretty welcome due to heavy traffic), this is the wrong way, as the browser always requests the file from the server and not get it from the cache if it has been cached.

Comment: Charlotte, you are right. I updated my answer. I now use the file time as token.

Comment: It worked!
I still don't know why my browser is doing this to me but it worked like a charm.
Thanks!